# MVC RedirectToAction appears to execute the (redirected) Action multiple times on live but once in dev

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm scratching my head on this.

I have a 'booking confirmation' action that sends a confirmation email to the customer after being returned from a 3rd party payment provider's website (where payment is made). The flow is:

1. Generate return URL and pass to the 3rd party payment provider's website
2. Customer makes the payment and their script returns the user based on the return URL we give

(note that all works fine)

3. On return, a "PaymentReturn()" controller action queries the payment to see if it was successful.
4. If so, the action redirects (using RedirectToAction) the customer to a "BookingConfirmation()" action where a confirmation email is triggered.

It is this Confirmation() action that triggers multiple times and the customer gets 6 emails!

I can't work out why this is happening but I do know that the PaymentReturn action is only called once however the "BookingConfirmation()" action (called by the RedirectToAction within the PaymentReturn() action is called 6 times. So it appears that either the RedirectToAction is triggering multiple times or the BookingConfirmation() action is deciding to 'fire' several times.

Here's a very basic summary of the code:

```
public ActionResult PaymentReturn(int bid, int pid)
{
    // Send myself an email message to alert this controller has been called
    // I GET THIS EMAIL ONCE

    // Use a web service to get the result
    CardPaymentQueryResponse cardPaymentQueryResponse = new Adelante3DSecure().CardGetCardPaymentDetails(pid);

    // Assuming all is good do the redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", new { b = bid });
}

public ActionResult BookingConfirmation(int bid)
{    
    // Send myself an email message to alert this controller has been called
    // I GET THIS EMAIL 6 times   

    // Send the confirmation emails to the customer
    // They get them 6 times
}
```

If I run the same code on my local development environment and step through the code the BookingConfirm() action executes ONCE and I get ONE email... on the live environment (single server - no failover) I get the 6 (so do the customers).

I'm at a loss what to try next in order to understand why this should happen.

Comment: What does fiddler show request wise when you are running through this and not debugging, even though you get multiple emails do you still see a single request? There isn't really enough here to go on to help troubleshoot from the outside looking in. Could there be a bug in the base email code as well? Have you tried bouncing the app pool on the production server?

Comment: Yes, appreciate there is precious little in this post to throw any insights. In reality it really is that simple though... Restarting the app pool doesn't alter anything, Fiddler (on dev) shows the request to the confirmation only happening once and I get duplicated emails within that action for both .NET SmtpClient and the 3rd party Mailgun emailing system - so its definitely the action that is executing multiple times (but only on production). Bizarre.

Comment: Has this issue been fixed? I ended up on this thread due to facing a similar thing and believing RedirectToAction() was the culprit, but in fact the issue was JS related in my case. I bet you also had some bugs in the logic that were causing multiple calls to be made.